# two classes, initialization of first class depends on the second class and vice versa

Tags: java

out of curiosity, I somehow came up with two classes, where the initialization of one class depends on an instance of the other class, as shown:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //How to initialize an instance of class One or class Two 
    }
}

class One{
    Two t;
    One(Two t){
        this.t = t;
    }
}

class Two{
    One o;
    Two(One o){
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

I was just wondering is it possible to initialize an instance of class One or class Two? If it is not possible, has anyone ever encountered similar situations in their projects? Is there a way to workaround this inter-dependency problem?

Comment: you can initialize it first with `One()` constuctor , then pass it to second ones constructor

Comment: i mean `One one = new One();` and `Two two = new Two();` after that use them to set values

Comment: this is not logical , i think you can change the structure of code , we do it in databases , when we have loops like this we change the architecture to remove the loop that created by relations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually u can simply instantiate any of them with reference to the other class is null

For example you can write

```
One o = new One(null);
Two t = new Two(o);
o.t = t; // or use a setter
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding an example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a setter in each object for the other type and remove them from the constructor.

```
public class One {

   private Two two;

   public void setTwo(Two two) {
       this.two = two;
   }
}
```

And

```
public class Two {

   private One one;

   public void setOne(One one) {
       this.one = one;
   }
}
```

Now

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    One one = new One();
    Two two = new Two();

    one.setTwo(two);
    two.setOne(one);
}
```

This is the simplest way but a better question would be: why exactly do you need this?

Comment: Cycle breaking needs only one side to forego constructor injection.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik correct but I wanted to show the most verbose way to do it. There are of course lots of different ways to minimize this type of dependency instantiation.

Comment: It's something that just came to me, I'm not sure why or when this is needed, but just curious what to do when this actually happens in real life

Answer (score 1):

If you have two classes with dependency each other a simple solution is to create both references only in one of them as follow:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        b.setA(this);
    }

    ...
}

public class B {
    private A a;

    public B() {
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    ...
}
```

And you can instantiate them as follow:

```
B b = new B();  // Here a doesn't yet exists so is correct 
                // that a is not referenced from b
A a = new A(b); // The constructor of A create both references 
                // from a to b and from b to a

// Here a references b and viceversa
```